# How to Find an xpath with some string contained and some not contained in the div?(Xpath not contains)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
**Problem :** How to Find an xpath with some string contained and some not contained in the div?(Xpath not contains)?

**Below are three examples** 

1)<div>You are now connected to Customer Care Virtual Assistant.</div>
2)<div>You are now connected to sumit.</div>
3)<div>You are now connected to dev.</div>

I have tried *//*[contains(text(),'You are now')]*
```

this xpath as well but it gives me 3 results and want only to fetch for values which does not contain virtual

```
i am currently using this xpath - *//*[text()[contains(.,'You are now ') and not[contains(.,'Virtual')]]*

It's not working for me , let me know what mistake i am doing here.

Any help will be appreciated ,

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.Try the following `xpath`.

```
//*[contains(.,'You are now') and not(contains(.,'Virtual'))]
```

Comment: This worked actually , but to be precise for the text:  The correct answer for me came to be //*[contains(.,'You are now') and not(contains(.,'Virtual'))]/text()

Comment: Thanks for the help , Upvoted the answer as well @KunduK

Comment: You have asked for the xpath which I have posted for the selenium.The xpath you posted with /text() is not supported by selenium.

Comment: I was able to find it in dev tools , /text() line does not support in selenium, Your Xpath is absolutely correct wrt selenium -My bad . Thanks for the help again

Comment: @k.sahni : Please accept the answer if this resolve to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try another solution

```
//a[not(contains(text(), 'Virtual')) and contains(.,'You are now')]
```

or

```
//a[not(contains(text(), 'Virtual')) and contains(text(),'You are now')]
```

Comment: This is giving me multiple results as it's finding all the texts which do not contain "Virtual" and not the exact result which i wanted...I have posted the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use:
1- use "starts-with" function.

```
div[starts-with(@id,'something')]
```

2- use "contains" function.

```
 div[contains(@id,'something')]
```

or

3- use full xpath, that id is not necessary to use attributes

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

Comment: 1)Starts with gets me the virtual text as well which i don't want

Comment: 2)Contains gives me both results , which is exactly the question and 3)It's not a good practice to use absolute xpath as div no's might change and will be a problem in the future....